# Is it possible to connect my android app with single parse.com app for both data and push?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am trying to connect my android app to my parse.com app by push. But I want to connect for both push and data because I need to keep my data both in parse and local database. How I can do it?

**I am tying to connect by writing the code below inside the onCreate() but it is not working**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //local data store enable
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    //parse initialize
    Parse.initialize(this, "lltSPqZ49DfZe8RRKECVdXeK7sv8Jv8nTVE3tlYa", "aIKyaF7kfTSIxIROR2NSWrZg7mA9S4JaR675ZOhg");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

when I remove the line `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);`

my app connects but i cant enable my local datastore. I need to enable both push and local data store. what I can do?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move your code in the Application.onCreate instead of Activity.onCreate. To do that you need to create a class that extends Application, and add it to the Manifest:

App.java

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "lltSPqZ49DfZe8RRKECVdXeK7sv8Jv8nTVE3tlYa", "aIKyaF7kfTSIxIROR2NSWrZg7mA9S4JaR675ZOhg");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
  }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml add `android:name=".App"` in your `<application>` tag

Also, you should tell us what do you mean by "Not Working". It's pretty hard to help you just by guessing what could be wrong (I probably should have left a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation…).

Comment: I did all the instructions u said. Not working means in quick start when I am trying to test it fails.

Comment: Any error message? Which quickstart are you doing (they have several)? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: It works now. I made a silly mistake. so previously it wasn't working. thanks for your help and valuable time.